# Curl in PHP having problems with redirects

Tags: php, parsing, curl

Well, here's the code:

```
<?
// Getting the comic page
if (!empty($_GET['c'])) $id = $_GET['c'];
else $id = "new";

$url = "http://www.explosm.net/comics/$id/";

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/6.0.447.0 Safari/534.2"); 

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

(it's actually longer, but that's the part I have problem with)

So, the problem is: if I specify strip's ID in GET argument "c" (such as "2126"), everything works ok, and the strip's page gets loaded into $result var.

However, if I specify a term, such as "random" or "new" (both of these work fine on explosm website, you can check that if you want), $result just equals to nothing.
To test that, you can use this page: `http://expmo.1free.ws/test.php` ( `http://expmo.1free.ws/test.php?c=2126` works ok, but `http://expmo.1free.ws/test.php` and `http://expmo.1free.ws/test.php?c=random` doesn't)

Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: Try setting `CURLOPT_HEADER` to `true` and checking what it will show you.

Comment: Are you sure $result is 'nothing'? If curl fails, it returns false, which would print out as a blank. Try something like `if ($result === FALSE) { die("Curl error: " . curl_error($curl)); }` after your `curl_exec()` call

Comment: I withdraw my comment - Marc's was way more descriptive.

Using your example code - I have no problems running locally on XAMPP.

Comment: Actually, I didn't have any problems running locally either. But when I try to use this code on hosting, I get this problem.
Yes, Marc was right, $result is false, but curl_error($curl) returns nothing (or maybe false too :D)

Comment: Have you tried using CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS also?

Comment: Yes, it didn't help. Well, I guess I'll have to manually parse Location header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of PHP are you using? If `safe_mode` is enabled, curl will not follow redirects even when `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` is set. If you enable error reporting and see:

> Warning: curl_setopt()
>   [function.curl-setopt]:
>   CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be
>   activated when in safe_mode or an
>   open_basedir is set...

Then you know you'll have to follow the redirects manually (since you're on shared hosting and likely cannot change the `safe_mode` or `open_basedir` settings) by parsing the response code and `Location` header yourself.

Comment: Well, my host (1free.ws) says safe mode is off on it's main page.